# Error trying to trim characters from a string

Tags: objective-c, string

I have the following code:

```
if (
    [[self.input.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet
    ]].length > 0
)
```

It's not compiling or running properly. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: what error does it say?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra bracket at the beginning of the method call.

```
if ([self.input.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
     [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]].length > 0) {}
```